# Android: Fill Gallery with TextViews

Tags: android

I am trying to make a Gallery that uses TextViews instead of ImageViews, but I cannot seem to make a working adapter. How can I use an adapter to fill the Gallery with TextViews?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just extend BaseAdapter like so:

```
public class GalleryTextAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

  Context context;

  GalleryTextAdapter(Context context){
    this.context = context;        
  }

  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = li.inflate(R.layout.mylayout, null);

    TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.mylayout_text);
    tv.setText("some text");
    return convertView;
  }
```

and assign it to the gallery using:

```
Gallery gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
gallery.setAdapter(new GalleryTextAdapter(this));
```

Comment: @MOST2K2 No, don't do that, it's wrong. Either A) you want to return the View that contains the TextView, therefore you return `convertView`, or B) You want to return the TextView, so you should *just inflate a TextView and return that*.

Comment: the gallery does not recycle the view, so convertview is always NULL, that i wanted to say with my comment. sure what you786 said is absolutely correct.